# What situation can trigger horizontalScrollView's onScrollChanged event?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a problem with HorizontalScrollView. I have overriden `onScrollChanged` with only watching ***x*** scroll position value. When I am touching the screen and moving my finger, the value in `onScrollChanged` is correct. When I release my finger each value appears twice in my logcat. It seems that a position value triggered the event twice after my finger left the screen.

First, I created a class that extends from HorizontalScrollView and overriden onScrollChanged

```
public class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
        Log.i("12345", String.valueOf(x) + " " + String.valueOf(oldx));
    }
}
```

**Summary:** 
When I am touching the screen and moving, each value appears once.
After my finger left the screen, each value apprears twice.
Please help me solve this problem. I want to know where the second call is from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this is that when **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** motion event is fired, **onScrollChanged** is called again. Add these methods to your scroll view to suppress that event, which will fix your problem.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I added these overrided function to my code, and the result is the **ACTION_UP** motion event is canceled. I think before I add the functions. The **ACTION_DOWN** and **ACTION_UP** call **onScrollChanged**. When I am touching the screen and moving my finger, **ACTION_MOVE** call **onScrollChanged**.Am I right?

Comment: yes, action move calls onScrollChanged but also ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP. Good to hear that you figured it out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It lets me know details that I never think before.